# Code not working for checking file size in batch file

Tags: if-statement, batch-file

```
:loop2
ping 1.1.1.1 -n 1 -w 10000 >nul
for %%I in (mesh0.1bb_intact.f06) do set %%checka=%%~zI
ping 1.1.1.1 -n 1 -w 20000 > nul
for %%I in (mesh0.1bb_intact.f06) do set %%checkb=%%~zI
IF NOT %checkb% EQU %checka% goto :loop2
```

This is in a batch file and ive got it to assign checka and checkb using the double %%.
But how can I fix the IF NOT ?
If they are not equal then wait until they are equal... if effectively what I want my code to do. But it just ends at the IF statement, probably saying blahblahblah is not expected at this  time (I dont know because it closes too quickly)
Thanks for any help.

Comment: you can put a PAUSE at the end to be able to see the error message, or run it via command prompt.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are confused about when to use `%%`. When you set an environment variable, you `set varName=value`. Your varName is simply a string, no % needed. Your value is in the FOR `I` variable, you are in a batch file, so you use `%%~zI`.

```
:loop2
ping 1.1.1.1 -n 1 -w 10000 >nul
for %%I in (mesh0.1bb_intact.f06) do set checka=%%~zI
ping 1.1.1.1 -n 1 -w 20000 > nul
for %%I in (mesh0.1bb_intact.f06) do set checkb=%%~zI
IF NOT %checkb% EQU %checka% goto :loop2
```

Comment: THANK YOU!!! it worked... this is the first time using DOS for me so I am learning as I go along here.

Answer (score 1):

As an alternative method, see `HELP SET` and `HELP CALL` and try the following code...

```
call :getfilesize file1 checka
call :getfilesize file2 checkb
IF %checka% LSS %checkb% (
  echo size of file1 %checka% less than size of file2 %checkb%
) ELSE (
  echo size of file1 %checka% greater than or equal size of file2 %checkb%
)
goto :eof
:getfilesize
set %2=%~z1
goto :eof
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but there is too much in your code that I am unfamiliar with, don't want to bite off more than I can chew.  Thanks again